# Grid and ungrid plot using R and tcltk

Tags: r, plot, tcl, tk-toolkit, gridlines

I plot data in a tcl tk window like this.

```
a <- tktoplevel()
b <- tkrplot(a, function()plot(cars, col="red"))
tkpack(b)
```

In my window, I use check button to put or remove grid to the plot.

```
require(tcltk)
require(tkrplot)

a <- tktoplevel()
tkbind(a, "<Destroy>", function()if(exists("cbValue"))tclvalue(cbValue) <- "3")
b <- tkrplot(a, function()plot(cars, col="red"))
tkpack(b)

cb <- tkcheckbutton(a)
cbValue <- tclVar("0")
tkconfigure(cb,variable=cbValue)
tkpack(cb)

x <- TRUE
while(x){
    tkwait.variable(cbValue)
    if(tclvalue(cbValue)=="1")
        tkrreplot(b, function(){ plot(cars, col="red"); grid() })
    else if(tclvalue(cbValue)=="0")
        tkrreplot(b, function()plot(cars, col="red"))
    else x <- FALSE
}
```

My problem is : In this example, I use `cars` data but actually I use a huge data. So, the method above (plot and then replot) takes too long do be done.

My question is : Is there a way to definetely plot the graph, and then add or remove grid without replotting it ?

THank you.